# Bad URLs on Stack Exchange Data Explorer cause yellow screen of death (YSOD)

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Trying to access a nonexistent URL on Stack Exchange Data Explorer causes a yellow screen of death. Example: http://odata.stackexchange.com/users/d

Comment: ok, Im on to it :) thanks for the report

Comment: status-completed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [cleaned up this](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Controllers/QueryController.cs?spec=svnae6a7498aa3d142488fd65eb1d2ce75f91c2458b&r=ae6a7498aa3d142488fd65eb1d2ce75f91c2458b) and a bunch of other places where this was happening today.

Essentially I was being a bit to greedy with my route matching, I went through the routes and changed it so when we expect a number we will only match to a number.

So, for example we had a few routes like so:

`[Route(@"{sitename}/qte/{savedQueryId}/{slug?}", RoutePriority.Low)]`

Which I rewrote to:

`[Route(@"{sitename}/qte/{savedQueryId:\d+}/{slug?}", RoutePriority.Low)]`

Additionally I sprinkled a few PageNotFounds in some strategic places.